# Are Bibek Debroy's translations of Puranas, Mahabharata reliable?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, translation

Are [Bibek Debroy's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibek_Debroy) translations of Puranas, Mahabharata reliable?

Comment: It would be difficult to answer unless we go through his translations one by one. And we also don't know how much Sanskrit he learnt. Because his higher studies were into Economics.

Comment: @TheLittleNarutowhat english translation would you suggest then >

Comment: I didn't study any of his work. So may not be able to suggest. Also note that he is an economist and not even a scholar or Acharya.

Comment: It's reliable according to most people I have interacted with. There are only a few translation errors which are easy to notice.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto it doesn't seems wise enough to dismiss the translations of a person just because that person in question didn't had any higher studies in Sanskrit. The English translation of the Yāgñavalkyasmṛti & a treatise on the Hindu law composed by J. R. Gharpure, who was an advocate by profession practising in the Bombay High Court is heavily quoted by later scholars like P. V Kane.

Comment: Can we ensure that whoever is in this platform giving their own translations of Sanskrit texts is certified to have undergone higher studies in Sanskrit language ?

Comment: I am going though Bibek’s translation of Valmiki Ramayana along with valmikiramayana.net and they both agree 99% of the time. The place where it’s different, Bibek has footnotes as to why he chose to translate it that way. So at least his Ramayana translations seem faithful (inasmuch as another source translates it similarly)

Comment: i was asking because i read really bad reviews about Bibek's translations on Quora

Comment: @SophieClad Usually new translators rely on old translations. i saw a post on twitter where Debroy copied completely Ganguly's translation in one snippet.  But still there are many translations of Puranas and Ithihas and you can find them on site or even Archive.  But still can't comment fully on his translation. Also, this question can be opinion based i feel.

Comment: Do his books have the various Stothras translated or transliterated? Are there reliable English translations of Puranas, where Stothras are transliterated?

Comment: @student yes there is one by kl joshi markande puran